# Recycler View Showing a card with null values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a Database Structure as

[image]

I want to load each dates post as different item in recyclerView i.e

18 Oct08:52 Am as one item.

18 Oct7:31 Pm as another.

So for this I am using **firebase Ui** for Database .
and my reference is as

```
r2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads").child("Wheat").child(S).child(D).child(T).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
```

But I receive a card stating null values.

So my question how should I initialize the database reference so that all the item are displayed in `RecyclerView`.

And this is my `RecyclerView`s code.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RecyclerCropView> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecyclerCropView>().setQuery(r2, RecyclerCropView.class).build();
                        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder2> Fbra1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder2>(options) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder2 holder, int position, @NonNull RecyclerCropView model) {
                                holder.setProductImage(model.getProduct_Image());
                                holder.setProduct(model.getProduct());
                                holder.setMax(model.getMaximumPrice());
                                holder.setQuantityUnit(model.getQuantityUnit());
                                holder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
                            }

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public ViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_post, parent, false);
                                return new ViewHolder2(v);
                            }
                        };
                        Fbra1.startListening();
                        Fbra1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyPost.this));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(Fbra1);
```

Comment: move Fbra1.startListening(); to the onStart method

Comment: What will that do

Comment: I think there is a problem in reference 
I cannot get weather reference is intalized correctly or not

Comment: try this, r2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads2").child("Wheat").child("Delhi").child("New Delhi").child(delhi).child("09 Oct07:46 AM"); and don't give the space New Delhi and date format . hope it's help full

Comment: where are you use uid don't show the your firebase data?   why are you this class FirebaseAuth? and put the your logcat error also .